# Find all the words containing more than 10 letters in string from text file

Tags: c#, string

Down below I have written code that successfully checks if the text file I enter has the character    "A" in it. It returns yes or no based on the result. However, **now I would like to list all the words bigger than 10 characters**. Please note that I use `ReadAllText` when I read the string. Therefore the whole text file is within the same string. I'm looking for the way to think rather than oven-ready code. Thank you all!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace TESTING
{
    class Testing
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ask user for the filename
            string userInput = fetchFileName("Enter the textfile you want to view: ");

            //test if the filename writes anything to console
            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(userInput);

            string theFileContents = analyseFile(fileContents);
            //Console.WriteLine(theFileContents);
            Console.ReadLine();         
        }

       private static string analyseFile(string fileContents)
       {
            string str = fileContents;
            if (str.Contains("A"))                
            {
               Console.WriteLine("YES");                   
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO");
            }
            return str;
       }

       private static string fetchFileName(string askFileName)
       {
            Console.WriteLine(askFileName);
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            return userAnswer;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use something along the lines of var meningRäknare = text.Where(mening => mening == '.').Count(); and instead of '.' use number of characters without blankspaces?

Comment: `fileContent.Split(' ').Where(word => word.Length >= 10);`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, because that's not what we do here...

Comment: @MatthewAbbott In fairness, he says "I'm looking for the way to think rather than oven-ready code"

Comment: @MatthewAbbott - Well, we're [not totally against it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @MatthewAbbott Right, so I'm supposed to learn it by myself? If this was for a job interview would it be different? I'm still in the learning process. I did not offer empty code, I actually tried it for myself. Clearly stated: I'm not looking for a piece of code that I can copy and paste. I'm trying to learn, I must be allowed to ask questions, homework or not..

Comment: You can use simple regex `\w{10,}`.

Answer (score 4):

Since your file is in a string, you could use `string`'s [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to convert it to tokens ("words"):

```
var tokens = fileContents.Split(' ', '\t', '\n', '\r');
```

With an array of tokens in hand, use the filtering technique that you prefer to keep only 10-character words. C# offers many choices to do that - you could use a `for` loop, a `foreach` loop, or use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method provided by LINQ.

Comment: @fuchs777: i guess OP understands how to extend this list.

Comment: @TimSchmelter No offense, but I usually prefer contributing usable stuff or hard facts rather than guesswork

Comment: @fuchs777: but this answer shows already how to split by multiple characters(as opposed to the other). What's so difficult in extending the split-characters? Nobody knows what OP actually  wants to use as split character(s). For example, are these word separators or part of words: `{([|])/²"#-`? The correct answer is: we don't know.

Answer (score 2):

just split your fileContent in words using `String.Split(' ')` and check then make a LINQ-query on the resulting array returning every word with Length > 10.

Sth. like this:

```
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(userInput);
var result = fileContents.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Length > 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Split` as below:

```
ArrayList ar=new ArrayList(); // list of strings with the lenghth of greater than 10
String[] userInputWords=userInput.Split(' ', '\t', '\n', '\r');
foreach(String str in userInputWords){
   if (str.Length()>10){
      ar.add(str);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore, use a strong typed `List<String>
`.

Comment: great, it just was a help to understand the alg, the focus is on **Split** and checking the **Length**

Comment: that's not a c# `foreach`

Comment: sorry it was a typo, I'm recently working on Java! that's why of that Typo

Answer (score 0):

This should work but is not tested

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ask user for the filename
            string userInput = fetchFileName("Enter the textfile you want to view: ");

            //test if the filename writes anything to console
            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(userInput);

            string theFileContents = analyseFile(fileContents);
            //   Console.WriteLine(theFileContents);

            foreach (var item in tenOrMore(fileContents))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> tenOrMore(string fileContents)
        {
            foreach (var item in fileContents.Split(' ', '\t', '\n', '\r'))
            {
                if (item.Length.CompareTo(10) > 0)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }

        private static string analyseFile(string fileContents)
        {
            string str = fileContents;
            if (str.Contains("A"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO");
            }
            return str;
        }

        private static string fetchFileName(string askFileName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(askFileName);
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            return userAnswer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, more naive way is to start from the beginning of the string and increment letter counter every time you encounter anything that isn't a whitespace character.

When you do encounter a whitespace, see if the letter counter is > 10. If yes, the word was longer than 10 characters. Reset letter counter to 0 and continue searching for words until the end of file.

This approach has an advantage of not doing splitting and extra string allocation, which is may be a lot of work for large files with many words.

Pseudocode:

```
letterCount = 0
wordCount = 0
letter = GetNextLetter()

while (isNotEndOfFile())
{
    if (notAWhitespace(letter))
    {
        letterCount++
    }
    else
    {
        if (letterCount > 10) { wordCount++ }
        letterCount=0
    }
    letter = GetNextLetter()
}
if (letterCount > 10) { wordCount++ }
```